# pyppeteer and javascript query

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pyppeteer

Im trying to migrate a node project, that uses puppeteer, to a python project that uses pyppeteer.

I have the below, javascript query, that is working correctly.

```
const values = await page.evaluate(
        () => [...document.querySelectorAll('.table')]
            .map(element => element.getAttribute('data-options'))
    );
```

When I try to do the same in python/pyppeteer:

```
values = await page.evaluate('''() = > [...document.querySelectorAll('.table')]
                   .map(element= > element.getAttribute('data-options'))
    ''')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pytabledata/main.py", line 30, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pytabledata/main.py", line 23, in main
    }''')
  File "/home/user/Envs/pytabledata/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/page.py", line 1158, in evaluate
    return await frame.evaluate(pageFunction, *args, force_expr=force_expr)
  File "/home/user/Envs/pytabledata/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/frame_manager.py", line 295, in evaluate
    pageFunction, *args, force_expr=force_expr)
  File "/home/user/Envs/pytabledata/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/execution_context.py", line 55, in evaluate
    pageFunction, *args, force_expr=force_expr)
  File "/home/user/Envs/pytabledata/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/execution_context.py", line 114, in evaluateHandle
    helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails)))
pyppeteer.errors.ElementHandleError: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

How can I make the query work in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The javascript code has typos on arrow operator: `= >` (redundant space). After fixing them, the code runs well in my machine:

```
values = await page.evaluate('''() => [...document.querySelectorAll('.table')]
                   .map(element => element.getAttribute('data-options'))
    ''')
```